# Why my onChange do not work when state have object on ReactJs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I tried to build a app use ReactJS by ES6

```
class MyApp extends React.Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      employee:{
      name: 'hello',
      birthday: ''
      },
      price: ''
    }
    this.handleValueChange = this.handleValueChange.bind(this);
  }
  handleValueChange(event){
    valueName = event.target.name
    this.setState({[valueName]: event.target.value});
  };
  render(){
    return(
    <form>
      <input type="text" placeholder="name" value={this.state.employee.name} onChange={this.handleValueChange} name="name"/>
      <input type="text" placeholder="name" value={this.state.price} onChange={this.handleValueChange} name="price"/>
    </form>
    )
  }
}
```

As my Code, I used `handleVauleChange` in `onChange` event to change the default state of the input html tag.If the data in `this.state` is object(like employee), the `handleVauleChange` function will not work, but the data is like price, it will work fine.

Why has it happened?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `setState` for the name input should be like this...

```
this.setState({
    employee: {
        [valueName]: event.target.value
    }
});
```

Not sure how dynamic the state structure you need but for one level deep structure, you can do something like this...

```
handleValueChange(event) {
    const valueName = event.target.name;
    const parent = valueName.indexOf('.') !== -1 ? valueName.split('.')[0] : false;
    if (parent) {
        this.setState({
            [parent]: {
                [valueName]: event.target.value
            }
        });
    } else {
        this.setState({
            [valueName]: event.target.value
        });
    }
}
```

and on your input fields...

```
<input 
    type="text" 
    placeholder="name" 
    name="employee.name"
    value={this.state.employee.name} 
    onChange={this.handleValueChange} />
<input 
    type="text" 
    placeholder="price" 
    name="price"
    value={this.state.price} 
    onChange={this.handleValueChange} />
```

Comment: I tired to use your code, but the employee.name is uncontrolled

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by employee.name is uncontrolled. The `handleValueChange` method works without having to define the employee keyword in your `setState`. You'll just need to use the dot notation when specifying your input name attribute.

Comment: I used your code and console told me `Warning: MyAppForm is changing an uncontrolled input of type text to be controlled. Input elements should not switch from uncontrolled to controlled (or vice versa). Decide between using a controlled or uncontrolled input element for the lifetime of the component.`

Comment: Do you have other input elements other the these two fields? Check if you have any input field that have `defaultValue` attribute.

Answer (score 1):

created jsbin:

http://jsbin.com/vopixexixe/edit?js,console,output#J:L14

In name input your setting input value from this.state.employee.name which is "hello" but on change your setting changed value to this.state.name

but in case of price your setting input value from this.state.price and updating to this.state.price, so value is reflecting.

Comment: Can let the input value is controlled?

Comment: It works fine now! thx, but browser console tells me `Warning: MyAppForm is changing an uncontrolled input of type text to be controlled. Input elements should not switch from uncontrolled to controlled (or vice versa). Decide between using a controlled or uncontrolled input element for the lifetime of the component.`

Answer (score 0):

In case of "name" you edit state.name and you want to edit state.employee.name I think

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: You have a state object that has 'employee', 'birthday' and 'price' properties. But the 'employee' propertie is also an object that has a property called 'name' - and this is what you are trying to modify. When you change 'price' value this work but when you want to change the name you should change 'employee.name' value and not just 'name' value.